# Can't send email in Contact.jsx component in Astro.js using Emailjs but it's not doing anything

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I've attempted to setup a contact form using Emailjs in my Astro project using 2 different ways, one using the template from the Emailjs docs, https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/, and the other from a tutorial. In my Astro project, which does have react added to it and emailjs installed, the form doesn't work using either of the 2 ways.

I created a react app just to see if the same form component would work there and it did. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is with my react form component in Astro.js.

When I hit submit I don't get an error. The form acts as if it's been submitted and the values clear but nothing actually gets sent and the URL changes from `http://localhost:4321/` to `http://localhost:4321/?` when I use Way 1. When I use Way 2 it'll change the URL from `http://localhost:4321/` to `http://localhost:4321/?user_name=asdfadf&user_email=test%40gmail.com&message=asdfadfasdfadf`.

Way 1 (From YouTube Tutorial) -

```
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

const Contact = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const serviceId = 'service_dighcxs';
    const templateId = 'template_gxyynmw';
    const publicKey = '0KNtQ2nWh28eb1DE-';

    const templateParams = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message,
    };

    emailjs
      .send(serviceId, templateId, templateParams, publicKey)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('email sent successfully', response);
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error sending email', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='emailForm'>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Your Name'
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type='email'
        placeholder='Your Email'
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <textarea
        placeholder='Your Message'
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      <button type='submit'>Send Email</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Way 2 (From Emailjs Docs) -

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'service_dighcxs',
        'template_gxyynmw',
        form.current,
        '0KNtQ2nWh28eb1DE-'
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          console.log('message sent', result);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>cheese</h1>
      <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type='text' name='user_name' />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type='email' name='user_email' />
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name='message' />
        <input type='submit' value='Send' />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

astro.config (showing react integration) -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

import react from "@astrojs/react";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), react()]
});
```